# As $N$ shrinks to $\{1\}$, the functions $F_N$ tend to $H$ in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $G$ be a compact group together with normalized Haar measure. Let $H\in L^2(G)$. For any open neighbourhood $N$ of the identity element $1$ of $G$, we define $$F_N(x)=\frac{1}{|N|}\int_G I_N(y)H(h^{-1}x)dy$$
where $I_N$ is the indicator function of $N$ and $|N|$ is the Haar measure of $N$. I try to show that as $N$ shrinks to $\{1\}$, the functions $F_N$ tend to $H$ in $L^2$.

---

$Attempt$: For any open neighbourhood $N$ of $1$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\|F_N-H\|_2^2 &=\int_G|(F_N-H)(x)|^2dx\leq \int_G(|F_N(x)|+|H(x)|)^2dx \qquad \text{by triangle inequality}
\\& =\int_G|F_N(x)|^2dx+2\int_G|F_N(x)||H(x)|dx+\int_G |H(x)|^2dx\qquad (1)
\end{align*}
Note that using Schwartz inequality we have
 $$\int_G|F_N(x)|^2dx=\frac{1}{|N|^2}\int_G|(I_N*H)(x)|^2dx\leq \frac{1}{|N|^2}\int_G\|I_N\|_2^2 \|H\|_2^2dx=\frac{1}{|N|^2}\|I_N\|_2^2 \|H\|_2^2$$ 
and 
$$\int_G|F_N(x)||H(x)|dx\leq \frac{1}{|N|}\|I_N\|_2\|H\|_2\|H\|_1$$
Therefore (1) becomes
\begin{align*}
\|F_N-H\|_2^2 &\leq \frac{1}{|N|^2}\|I_N\|^2\|H\|_2^2+\frac{2}{|N|}\|I_N\|_2\|H\|_2\|H\|_1+\|H\|_2^2
\\&=\underbrace{\frac{1}{|N|^2}|N|}_{(*)}\|H\|_2^2+\underbrace{\frac{2}{|N|}|N|^{1/2}}_{(**)}\|H\|_2\|H\|_1+\|H\|_2^2
\end{align*}
$Question$: As $N$ shrinks to $\{1\}$, the term $(**)\to 0$ but $(*)\to\infty$. Could anyone help me to find my mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you lose a lot of information using the triangle inequality in the first step. Instead, perhaps one can assume $H$ is continuous for the time being to see what the proof does: For any $\epsilon>0$, uniform continuity ensures that there exists a neighbourhood $N_0$ of the identity such that, if $y\in N_0$, then
$$
|H(y^{-1}x)-H(x)|<\epsilon \quad\forall x\in G
$$
Now if $N\subset N_0$, since the measure is normalized, you get
$$
\|I_N\ast H - H\|_{\infty} < \epsilon
$$
which in turn controls $\|I_N\ast H -H\|_2$.

Now for an arbitrary $H\in L^2(G)$, simply approximate by functions in $C(G)$.

Comment: Could you check my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $C(G)$ is dense in $L^2(G)$, there is a function $H_0
\in C(G)$ such that \begin{align}\|H_0-H\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\end{align}
The uniform continuity of $H_0$ ensures that there exists a neighbourhood $N_0$ of $1$ such that 
$$
y\in N_0\implies|H_0(y^{-1}x)-H_0(x)|<\sqrt{\epsilon /2} \qquad \text{for all $x\in G$}
$$
On the other hand, for any $x\in G$, if $N
\subseteq N_0$ is an open neighbourhood of $1$ then we have
\begin{align*}
|F_N(x)-H_0(x)|^2 &=\left|\frac{1}{|N|}\int_GI_N(y)H_0(y^{-1}x)dy-\frac{1}{|N|}\int_G I_N(y)H_0(x)dy \right|^2 
\\&=\frac{1}{|N|^2}\left|\int_GI_N(y)\big(H_0(y^{-1}x)-H_0(x)\big)dy \right|^2
\\&\leq \frac{1}{|N|^2}\left(\int_GI_N(y)|H_0(y^{-1}x)-H_0(x)|dy\right)^2
\\&<\frac{1}{|N|^2}\left(\int_G I_N(y)\sqrt{\epsilon /2} dy\right)^2=\epsilon/2 
\end{align*}
which implies that 
$$\sup_{x\in G} |F_N(x)-H_0(x)|^2<\epsilon/2$$ So we get
\begin{align}
\|F_N-H_0\|_2^2=\int_G |F_N(x)-H_0(x)|^2dx\leq \int_G
\sup_{x\in G}|F_N(x)-H_0(x)|^2dx<\epsilon/2
\end{align}
  By combining the results, we get
  $$\|F_N-H\|_2\leq \|F_N-H_0\|_2+\|H_0-H\|_2<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon\qquad\text{whenever $N
  \subseteq N_0$}$$